# Why does Visual Studio code style settings think DateTime is not a built-in type but Guid acts like it is?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, coding-style

I have it set so I have to use the explicit type for built-in and apparent types, and `var` everywhere else:

[image]

This works fine for `int` and even `Guid` but not for `DateTime`:

[image]

Why does it want to use `var` for `DateTime` variables instead of the explicit `DateTime` type?

Comment: Post code instead of image. Images can not be visible

Comment: built-in types are types you can call with lowercase letters, like `string`, `object`, `int`, etc.

Comment: @rory.ap Using VS 15.9.10, I don't see this behaviour. The editor does not underline anything and does not display the suggestion lightbulbs automatically. It does suggest using `var` if you manually invoke "Quick actions and refactorings", but the popup menu contains only "Use implicit type", not the more elaborate version you are showing.

Comment: @mjwills Still can't see it on 15.9.13. Ah, it does happen if I create a .NET Core project instead of a regular FW project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ya5y69ds?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), `DateTime` is not a built in type (see also [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/3aa643d44d005a6a501d9df165fa9d9e428e06f8/src/Workspaces/Core/Portable/Shared/Extensions/ITypeSymbolExtensions.cs#L635)).

Only lower case aliases like `int` or `string` are built in.

Your `Guid` example may work because the "[type is apparent](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/0ec91a960a6c733a5d37df29fe9a2839532fc8c7/src/Workspaces/CSharp/Portable/Utilities/CSharpTypeStyleHelper.State.cs#L72)".

That may explain why:

```
Guid h = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid i = h;
```

`h` is left alone, but `i` is not (since `NewGuid` is classed as a [creation method](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/0ec91a960a6c733a5d37df29fe9a2839532fc8c7/src/Workspaces/CSharp/Portable/CodeStyle/TypeStyle/TypeStyleHelper.cs#L153)).

I believe it doesn't work for `DateTime.Now` since it is not a [static method](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/0ec91a960a6c733a5d37df29fe9a2839532fc8c7/src/Workspaces/CSharp/Portable/CodeStyle/TypeStyle/TypeStyleHelper.cs#L153) (it is a property). But it does work for `DateTime.Parse` - for example.